# Are there reasons why DLL redirection won't work other than the presence of a manifest?

Tags: windows, windows-7, dll

We have a legacy VB6 application that uses Crystal Reports XI to generate printed reports. We've found through experience that the Crystal Reports print engine crashes if it picks up the wrong version of **usp10.dll** (the Windows Uniscribe library).

One customer is consistently having printing issues on their Windows 7 machines (running Windows 7 Enterprise, 32-bit). However, we have a few other customers running various editions of Windows 7 that are not having any problems.

On one of the machines that was having printing issues, I noticed that there was an older version of `usp10.dll` (one incompatible with Crystal Reports XI) in the folder `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office10\`. I'm not sure what application installed these files, because the customer doesn't have Office 2002 installed (so I assume another application installed them). However, I temporarily renamed the file and our application was able to print correctly, so it seems that our application was loading that version of the file originally, which was causing the crashes.

The crash only happens the moment the user tries to print a report. Our application has direct dependencies on **craxdrt.dll** (the Crystal Reports ActiveX Designer Runtime library) and **crviewer.dll** (the Crystal ActiveX Report Viewer library), and the crash happens whether we print directly through **craxdrt.dll** or through the Report Viewer control.

In the past, we have resolved this issue by copying a known good version of **usp10.dll** into our application's directory and creating an *.local* file to enable DLL redirection. At the customer site, I tried this, and also tried the alternate approach of creating a *.local* folder for our EXE and placing the **usp10.dll** in there, but neither approach worked on the machine I was connected to.

I did notice that **usp10.dll** is a "known" DLL in Windows (it has an entry in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\KnownDLLs`), but I tested our application on another Windows 7 machine (running Professional Edition, 32-bit) here that also had the DLL listed as a known DLL in the registry, and by using *Dependency Walker*, I could see that the redirection was working on that computer. This is somewhat confusing, since the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-redirection) states that known DLL's cannot be redirected. Also, as I implied in the question title, our main EXE does not use a manifest file (the Microsoft documentation states that the presence of a manifest, embedded or standalone, disables DLL redirection).

So, my question is, is there any other reason why DLL redirection would work on some machines and not others, and does this have anything to do with differences between Windows 7 and Windows XP? I had considered deleting everything in the `KnownDLLs` registry key, but since the redirection was working on a machine here that had the same set of `KnownDLLs`, I'm not sure that would actually resolve the issue, and I don't want to delete that key if I don't need to. I haven't yet had a chance to connect to the customer's machine again to run *Dependency Walker*, but I'm not sure I would be able to interpret its logs anyway (even on the machine where it was working, I saw a lot of *LoadLibrary* calls for **usp10.dll** pointing to a folder other than the redirected folder, but some calls were apparently redirected, so I'm not sure what that means either).

---

**EDIT**: I should have also mentioned that every computer we've checked also has another copy of `usp10.dll` in the `System32` folder. Looking at Chris's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400168/are-there-reasons-why-dll-redirection-wont-work-other-than-the-presence-of-a-ma/3400717#3400717) and [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150629150222/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/07/19/187752.aspx) by Larry Osterman explaining a bit more about how known DLLs work, I realized that that probably doesn't factor into the problem at all, since our program isn't loading the copy of `usp10.dll` that is in the `System32` folder.

---

**EDIT #2**: After playing around with *Dependency Walker* some more on my VB6 development machine (Windows XP SP3), where the printing has always worked, I was able to glean some information. I profiled our application in *Dependency Walker* and set it to log full path names, and it looks like one of the Crystal Reports dependencies (another Crystal Reports DLL) tries to load **usp10.dll** from multiple (hard-coded) paths before giving up and just asking for it by filename. It turns out that it tries to load it from the Crystal Reports `bin` folder first, then tries to load it from from `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office10\usp10.dll`. If it can't find it at either location, it just asks Windows for `usp10.dll` (which will grab the one in `System32`). But even this isn't consistent. Sometimes it asks for the file in the `Office10` folder, and then appears to ignore the fact that it couldn't find the file, while other times there are a series of *LoadLibrary* calls where it looks like the Crystal Reports code is actively looking for alternate copies of the file in different locations. Even more confusing is that at least one of the Crystal Reports components looks like it actually has a load-time dependency on **usp10.dll**, so that component always seems to get the copy in `System32`.

I'm still not 100% clear *why* the `.local` redirection wouldn't work in this situation on this customer's computers, but I think that partly explains why this particular customer is having problems, since all of the computers with the problem have an `Office10` folder with an apparently incompatible version of `usp10.dll` in it.

But, once again, I'm still left with the basic question: if these components are looking for this file in so many different places, how can I guarantee that they will all use the *same* copy?

Comment: On the computers that fail - is there a copy of usp10.dll in system32?

I could kind of understand this scenario as playing out like:
1. Because usp10.dll is listed as a known dll, the .local redirector us disabled.
2. If then, usp10.dll is NOT in system32, when the system attempts to load KnownDLLs for a process, usp10.dll is not found, and subsequent attempts to use an explicit path to load an incompatible version succeed.
Fixing this issue should be: install a copy in system32 if missing.

Comment: @Chris: The computers where it fails have a copy of usp10.dll in system32 in addition to the one in the Office10 folder. As far as I can tell, the one in system32 is fine, and the one in the Office10 folder is incompatible with Crystal, because if I rename that one to usp10.dll_ for example, Crystal Reports suddenly starts to work. What is confusing is that USP10.dll *is* listed as known DLL on the computers that fail, but Crystal Reports uses a combination of implicit and explicit dependencies on usp10.dll, which I think is complicating things even more.

Comment: According to another MSDN page I just found, the KnownDLLs registry key only affects implicitly-loaded DLLs, not DLLs that are loaded with `LoadLibrary`. According to Dependency Walker (running the program on my Windows 7 virtual machine), some Crystal components load the System32 version (because they have load-time dependencies on usp10.dll, i.e. implicit linking), some of the LoadLibrary calls also load the System32 copy as well, but other LoadLibrary calls keep loading the copy in Office10. It's physically loading _both_ DLLs into the process (LoadLibrary returns 2 different handles).

Comment: For the above test, I simulated the customer environment by creating a dummy Office10 folder and putting a copy of usp10.dll there (and left the original in system32). In this situation, the DLL is always loaded twice. What's even worse is that the at least one of the Crystal DLLs that uses usp10.dll appears to call functions in _each_ copy of the DLL. So when the Office10 DLL is actually a different version, it still causes Crystal to crash because it will still use that version of the DLL for certain function calls even though it's already loaded the one in system32...

Comment: Also, on Windows XP, there were `LoadLibrary` calls logged for `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.0\bin\usp10.dll`, so I thought I could fix the problem by putting a copy of usp10.dll in that folder. However, when ran the same test on Windows 7, none of the `LoadLibrary` calls were looking in that folder (they look in the Office10 folder). This folder wasn't in my `PATH` on my XP machine, so I have no idea why it's looking there in XP and not in Windows 7, otherwise I think putting it in that folder could've fixed this whole mess.

Comment: That kind of implies the worst combination of factors. KnownDlls is inhibiting .local - and explicit paths to LoadLibrary are loading other usp10.dll other than the known dll.

At this point, installing some kind of API hook on crystal reports dlls so you can intercept calls to loadlibrary seems to be the only real way forward.

Comment: Ok - ive modified my answer with the only hack I can think of to sort your situation out. It assumes you can integrate some c code into your VB app unfortunately.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for the help, but I actually found a simpler solution. I'll post the details in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was actually pretty simple, but it took me a while to figure out why it worked.

On the customer machine, I copied **usp10.dll from** `C:\Windows\System32` (which is known-good version) into the folder `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.0\bin` (where most of the Crystal components are installed). I then ran a `crdeploy.reg` file that was already present in in the `bin` folder: this file adds a `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Business Objects\Suite 11.0\Crystal Reports` key to the Registry and sets the value `CommonFiles` to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.0\bin`.

Since I couldn't connect to the customer's machine earlier today, I did some more testing of the issue on a Windows 7 virtual machine. Like I mentioned in one of my edits, on this computer Crystal Reports never looked in the `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.0\bin` directory for **usp10.dll**, so it would immediately try to load the copy in the `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office10` folder.

It turns out the when Crystal Reports calls `LoadLibrary`, it checks the following folders for **usp10.dll**:

- If `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Business Objects\Suite 11.0\Crystal Reports\CommonFiles` is present in the Registry, it calls `LoadLibrary` using that path.
- If the registry key is not present, or **usp10.dll** doesn't exist in that folder, Crystal Reports will call `LoadLibrary` with `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office10\usp10.dll` as the path.
- If the file isn't found in the `Office10` folder, it passes just the filename (`usp10.dll`) to `LoadLibrary`, which then causes Windows to load the copy in `System32`.

So, on my test Windows 7 machine, I didn't have the `CommonFiles` registry key set, so Crystal Reports always loaded the version of **usp10.dll** that was in the `Office10` folder, even after putting a copy of **usp10.dll** in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.0\bin`. Once I set the registry key to point to the right place, Crystal Reports loaded the correct version of the file.

On the customer's machine, the registry already had the `CommonFiles` path set to the right folder, but our application's setup program wasn't installing **usp10.dll** to that folder, so it was still picking up the copy in the `Office10` folder.

The final workaround given to the customer was stupidly simple:

1. Copy the version of **usp10.dll** from the `System32` into `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.0\bin`.
2. Run the `crdeploy.reg` file in the `bin` folder to ensure that the `CommonFiles` registry key exists and is pointing to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.0\bin`.

I had originally thought putting a copy of **usp10.dll** into the `bin` folder would fix the problem on the customer's machines, but like I said, this didn't work on my Windows 7 test machine because I was missing the `CommonFiles` registry key, so I was hesitant to consider the issued fixed.

Also, in case it helps anyone else experiencing this problem, the versions of **usp10.dll** involved were:

- 1.405.2416.1: This is the version in the `Office10` folder, and the one that causes Crystal Reports to crash. When you print a report, an access violation occurs when Crystal Reports calls one of the functions in **usp10.dll** (I don't have the original stacktrace, but I think it was the `ScriptApplyDigitSubstitution` function).
- 1.626.7600.16385: This is a known good version that works correctly with Crystal Reports. This version seems to be the one installed in Windows 7 by default.

There are other versions, such as installed by default in Windows XP in the `System32` folder that also work fine with Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought: .manifest files and all they imply were added to windows XP in 2002/2003.
Why the @#$% does your app - and the libraries your app uses for that matter - not use this technology to solve this little "dll-hell". It is *exactly* the scenario they were developed to solve.

Next, im pretty sure that "KnownDlls" only covers dlls that the OS actually finds in System32. Finding dll's in random path locations (as in a Office2002 folder) i would hope at least would fail some internal sanity check (is-the-dll-a-real-KnownDlls-candidate) test. And the PATH is searched after system folders, so by the time a usp10.dll is found in ...\Office10\ - it' cant be a real known dll (by definition).

Next, Im also sure that the .local file isn't doing what you think it is. The documentation for .local files makes no sense at all because all it really says is, the search order for dlls after a .local file is applies, is exactly the default search order for dll's normally - the exe folder is always searched BEFORE system folders anyway.

The only time .local actually makes a potential difference is when an application uses an explicit path to load a dll in a call to loadLibrary (or uses the altered search path flag to LoadLibrary or uses the SetDllSearchDirectory API). All cases where the exe or dll doing the loading is choosing a very specific dll - that you the app author wants to override in some way. .local files cannot (Seem to me anyway) change the search behaviour for any dll files that are specified by just their name.

So, if usp10.dll is installed into system32, its probably going to be picked up as a KnownDll and then used - despite your local copy (and .local file).
If its somewhere else on the path, the copy in your exe's folder should be used first anyway - (assuming LoadLibrary("usp10.dll") is the way the dll is loaded).

Even if you go to all the effort of creating an assembly to contain your known-good usp10.dll, and then made your app dependent on that, I still think that a fully qualified path passed to LoadLibrary will defeat any search logic at all - including looking for the dll in the list of dependent assemblies.

So, your problem confuses me. The usp10.dll used should be

- the one in system32 if present (because of KnownDlls overring the one in your exe's folder)
- the one in your application folder, because search logic will always find this one first if KnownDlls is a miss.

unless usp10.dll is actually a com dll, or there is a fully qualified path to it in the registry that consumers use to load it, in which case the one loaded should be :

- the one in your application folder, because this seems to be the one case where .local files might apply.

---

Given that the presence of the DLL in KnownDLLs is inhibiting the functionality of .local, and given that Crystal reports dlls are pathalogical ...

All I can suggest is:

This thread contains a function called PatchIAT - import it into your code.

Before using any functionality in the Crystal Reports dlls (That causes them to go looking for usp10.dll) - call LoadLibrary to get a handle to the dll, then call PatchIAT on the handle, to redirect the dll's call to LoadLibrary to a function your EXE implements.

In your EXEs LoadLibraryThunk procedure, pass on any calls to the system's LoadLibrary, unless its for an explicit path to usp10.dll - on those calls - return an error code.

[Disable antialiasing for a specific GDI device context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641401/disable-antialiasing-for-a-specific-gdi-device-context)

Comment: Only for information: usp10.dll is a "Uniscribe Unicode script processor". It exist in system32 directory and is explicitly in the list of `KnownDlls`.

Comment: @Oleg: Yeah, I should have mentioned that both machines I tested on actually had multiples copies of usp10.dll in different folders, including a copy in `System32`, but on the customer's machine with or without a `.local` file or folder, it kept loading the DLL from the `Office10` despite that fact. However, on a Windows 7 box here it would pull from the `Office11` folder (that machine doesn't have an `Office10` folder) if I _didn't_ use a `.local` file, and with the `.local` file present it would load it from the application's directory. It made no sense to me at all, hence the question.

Comment: @Chris: To clarify, `usp10.dll` is just a standard DLL, not a COM DLL. It's actually Crystal Reports that loads it, so I'm not clear on how it loads the DLL in the first place, although it could explain why Dependency Walker says it's loading the DLL from 2 different places at times (I guess it uses the full path sometimes and just the name other times when loading the DLL?). Still, the strange part is that `.local` redirection has actually fixed this issue at other customer sites, and it's very possible that I'm completely misunderstanding how it's supposed to actually work.

Comment: AFAIK, the other customer sites also had a copy of `usp10.dll` in `System32`. In the cases where those customers had printing problems, it was _always_ because there was an older version of `usp10.dll` in a random `OfficeXX` folder, and putting a `.local` file in our app's directory and putting a known-good copy of the DLL there would fix the problem. It sounds like the `.local` file might have been redundant since it seems like it should have picked up the DLL in the app directory anyway.

Comment: As for using a manifest file, I had considered that solution too, but for whatever reason I couldn't get that to work either (I was probably doing it wrong). The confusing part of the whole situation is that we've resolved the same issue for other customers, but it didn't work at this particular customer site.

Comment: @Chris: Looking the documentation again, it actually says this: The contents of a redirection file are ignored, but its presence causes Windows to check the application directory first whenever it loads a DLL, **regardless of the path specified to LoadLibrary or LoadLibraryEx**. That wording makes me think the point is that `.local` files will override `LoadLibrary` calls even if the program specified a full path to a specific version of the file, which isn't what would normally happen. That's my interpretation anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue on a TS running Server 2008 R2.  Error from Event log:

```
Log Name: Application
Source: Application Error
Date: 5/23/2012 10:32:37 AM
Event ID: 1000
Task Category: (100)
Level: Error
Keywords: Classic
User: N/A
Computer: 
Description:
Faulting application name: crw32.exe, version: 11.0.0.1282, time stamp: 0x422d5c77
Faulting module name: usp10.dll, version: 1.420.2600.5969, time stamp: 0x4bc88269
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00014ee4
Faulting process id: 0x1744
Faulting application start time: 0x01cd38f8ce57fbd5
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Business Objects\Crystal Reports 11\crw32.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office10\usp10.dll
```

I tried copying usp10.dll from \Windows\System32 into C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Business Objects\3.0\bin. Then ran the crdeploy.reg file but had to manually update the regkey to include (x86) due to 64bit OS on server. The Crystal Reports app still wouldn't recognize the DLL, it kept looking in the \Office10 folder. So I just renamed the copy of the DLL in that folder then copied from \System32 again. That worked like a charm, also the file versions on the DLL were exactly the same that Mike Spross posted.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem like a good idea to me to have extra copies that windows does not know about (How will it get updated?)

Why can't you call `LoadLibrary("usp10.dll")` yourself as the first thing you do at startup?

Comment: I agree it's not the most ideal solution to have two copies of the DLL, but I think even if the one in `System32` gets updated, it will still work, since I think any newer version that ships with Windows or an update should still be compatible with Crystal Reports. The version that comes with Office10 (1.405.2416.1) seems to be the only version that doesn't work with Crystal. None of customers have had printing issues after applying Windows service packs or updates so far.

Comment: I don't think calling `LoadLibrary` in our program will fix the problem of Crystal loading two DLL's in Windows 7 anyway. Since `usp10.dll` is a known DLL and `craxdrt.dll` (which is a Crystal component) implicitly links to `usp10.dll`, Windows will always load the copy in `System32` for that component. The other components that use `LoadLibrary` will load the DLL from whatever folder Crystal first finds the file in (i.e. it will look in the `CommonFiles` folder specified in the registry, then the `Office10` folder, and then `System32`).

Comment: Actually, I think I see your point: From the `LoadLibrary` documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28VS.85%29.aspx): _If lpFileName does not include a path and there is more than one loaded module with the same base name and extension, the function returns a handle to the module that was loaded first._ So, by calling `LoadLibrary("usp10.dll")` first, it should force every other `LoadLibrary` call to return the same handle instead of loading the DLL a second time. Is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: I think the problem with that approach is that Crystal Reports uses full paths when it calls `LoadLibrary`, so if I am reading the documentation correctly, that means it _wouldn't_ return the same handle as the original `LoadLibrary("usp10.dll")` (since the documentation says it only returns an existing handle if "`lpFileName` does _not_ include a path"). Or am I misunderstanding something?